# How to use a UNIX socket in a CGI program

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, cgi

I want to write a web interface for a program that has a UNIX socket based server interface, but it seems that it is impossible to successfully connect to it within the CGI program.

I looked at the httpd.conf file and searched the web, but nothing found. The CGI program is written C++. The UNIX socket is in a path allowed by the httpd server.

Comment: Maybe you should consider [FastCgi](http://fastcgi.com/) ...

Answer (score 2):

To connect to a unix local socket as a client, you first create an anonymous socket, e.g. for TCP:

```
int fd = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

You then create an appropriate `struct sockaddr_un` with the destination path:

```
struct sockaddr_un addr;
addr.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
strcpy(addr.sun_path, "/path/to/server/socket/file");
```

And call `connect()`:

```
connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

However, this is all copiously documented in man pages and online.  There is no C++ specific method unless you use a third party library; these are *nix specific extensions to standard C:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

The GNU C Reference Manual [has a chapter](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sockets.html).

Comment: It is not a problem related to how to implement a UNIX socket client program. I already implemented all this stuff. When I run the cgi as a stand alone program by shell it works just fine. When I test it using the http interface it not works, returning error on connect().

Comment: I'd say you have to restate your problem then -- but **do it in a new question**, and **be specific**.  Explain *in detail* what you've done, what it is mean to do, and what it actually does.  **Be explicit**.  If `connect()` returns an error, include the `errno` produced, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your server creates the socket without write permissions for 'group' and 'all': srwxr_xr_x.
So change it to all access (chmod 777 .. etc) after the server creates the pipe. Then, I bet, your CGI program will connect ... ;-)

Do the chmod after the bind .. in a c program it would look like this:

```
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, servlen) < 0) {
    perror("Error binding socket:");
    exit 1;
}

if (chmod(PipeName, 0777) == -1) {
    perror("Error in chmod:");
    exit 1;
}
```